# Read tooptip text using capybara

Tags: capybara

I am using tipsy gem for tooltip. How Can I read tooltip text using capybara?

Answer (score 3):

From what I see at [this page](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) tipsy renders `original-title` attribute.

To get this attribute in Capybara you can use [[] method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#%5B%5D-instance_method):

```
find('.class')[:original-title]
```